# Is any scriptures says that, Without chanting the names of the God, we are all living dead?

Tags: gods, identification-request

How does someone considered as a living dead if not chanting the names of God?

Comment: Do you want to identify which scripture says `Without chanting the names of the God, we are all living dead?` or why does scriptures say so? Currently, your question's title and body are not matching.

Comment: I need both, scripture and how it works, @TriyugiNarayanMani

Comment: @KailashChandraPolai It will better if you add where you read this or source for this information.

Comment: i heard it from a pundit staying near to me. so i do not have source @TheDestroyer, but he was telling it is written in Vedas as well as in Gita.

Answer (score 1):

Never to deny spirit(brahman) because the spirit is atman.

> Brahman was this
>   before; therefore it
>   knew even the Ātma
>   (soul, himself). I am
>   Brahman, therefore it
>   became all. And
>   whoever among the
>   gods had this
>   enlightenment, also
>   became That. It is the
>   same with the sages,
>   the same with men.
>   Whoever knows the
>   self as “I am
>   Brahman,” becomes
>   all this universe. Even
>   the gods cannot
>   prevail against him,
>   for he becomes their
>   Ātma. **Now, if a man
>   worships another god,
>   thinking: “He is one
>   and I am another,” he
>   does not know. He is
>   like an animal to the
>   gods. As many
>   animals serve a man,
>   so does each man
>   serve the gods. Even
>   if one animal is taken
>   away, it causes
>   anguish; how much
>   more so when many
>   are taken away?
>   Therefore it is not
>   pleasing to the gods
>   that men should know
>   this.**
>
> **— Brihadaranyaka
>   Upanishad 1.4.10**

**SIXTH ANUVAKA.**

> **He who knows the
>   Brahman as non-
>   existing, becomes
>   himself non-existing. He
>   who knows the Brahman
>   as existing, him we know
>   himself as existing.'** The
>   embodied Self of this
>   (bliss) is the same as
>   that of the former
>   (understanding).
>
> —[Taittrayi upnishad book 2.6](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/upanishads/taittiriya.asp)

so, there i think is no restriction of chanting name of god but it is said to read vedas which is itself great.