# Is Lord Ganesha considered same as the ultimate truth and reality (Brahman)?

Tags: shiva, krishna, upanishads, brahman, ganesha

Many Texts associate OM with cosmic creation and that OM is everything. Ganesha is associated with OM and hence known as oṃkārasvarūpa (Aum is his form).

The Ganapati Atharvashirsa states that Lord Ganesha is considered same as the ultimate truth and reality (Brahman).

From  [Ganapati Atharvashirsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganapati_Atharvashirsa),translation taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganesha):

> (O Lord Ganapati!) You are (the Trimurti) Brahma, Vishnu, and Mahesa. You are Indra. You are fire [Agni] and air [Vāyu]. You are the sun [Sūrya] and the moon [Chandrama]. You are Brahman. You are (the three worlds) Bhuloka [earth], Antariksha-loka [space], and Swargaloka [heaven]. You are Om. (That is to say, You are all this).

If Lord Ganesha is same as Brahman,then what about Lord Shiva and the Supreme Personality of Godhead Krsna.

Comment: Related - [Which scriptures portray Lord Ganesha to be the supreme God?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21542/5212)

Comment: All gods are equal if you have read vedas then indra,agni and soma are most prominent gods there but no god is said to be a low one. Leaving 10 major upnishads nowdays 13 left all are divided some vaishnava,shakta,shaiva,sanyasa etc. so even upnishad leaving first 10. No matter remember god one names diffrent sometimes **text diffrent**.

Comment: It's post which is considered as Supreme and not an individual..Indra, Ganapati, Prajapati, Saptrisis etc. are posts..As per Ramcharitmanas, Shiva & Parvati also worshipped Ganapati in their marriage (that means much before than their son Ganesha's birth)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very simple bro

like in vedas indra was a prominent diety agni,soma,surya etc but others too are great and are never marked less.

[Which Vedic verses describe Indra as Brahman?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19033/which-vedic-verses-describe-indra-as-brahman)

[Do any verses in the Vedas declare Agni to be supreme?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22574/do-any-verses-in-the-vedas-declare-agni-to-be-supreme)

[Which scriptures or Vedic hymns declare the Sun as the Supreme God (Brahman)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21307/which-scriptures-or-vedic-hymns-declare-the-sun-as-the-supreme-god-brahman)

[Do any Vedic verses depict Lord Vishnu to be supreme?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19872/do-any-vedic-verses-depict-lord-vishnu-to-be-supreme)

So its very common that gods apart from vedas apart every god is supreme in their texts or scriptues although all are supreme because all are one. :)

Now vedas declare it too:—

> 13 Glory to Gods, the mighty and
>   the lesser glory to Gods the
>   younger and the elder! Let us, if
>   we have power, pay the God
>   worship: no better prayer than
>   this, ye Gods, acknowledge.
>
> —[Rig veda 1.27.13](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01027.htm)

Vedas say to give equal respect to
all gods.

> 46 They call him Indra, Mitra,
>   Varuṇa, Agni, and he is heavenly
>   nobly-winged Garutmān.
>   To what is One, sages give many a
>   title they call it Agni, Yama,
>   Mātariśvan.
>
> — [Rig Veda: Rig-Veda Book 1:
>   HYMN CLXIV. Viśvedevas:46](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01164.htm)

Along Brihadaranyaka upnishada too throws light on it:—

**NINTH BRAHMANA**

> 1. Then Vidagdha
>      Sakalya asked him: 'How
>      many gods are there, O
>      Yagnavalkya?' He replied
>      with this very Nivid: 'As
>      many as are mentioned
>      in the Nivid of the hymn
>      of praise addressed to
>      the Visvedevas, viz.
>      three and three
>      hundred, three and
>      three thousand.'
>      'Yes,' he said, and asked
>      again: 'How many gods
>      are there really, O
>      Yagnavalkya?'
>      'Thirty-three,' he said.
>      'Yes,' he said, and asked
>      again How many gods
>      are there really, O
>      Yagnavalkya?'
>      'Six,' he said.
>      'Yes,' he said, and asked
>      again:' How many gods
>      are there really, O
>      Yagnavalkya?'
>      'Three,' he said.
>      'Yes,' he said, and asked
>      again: 'How many gods
>      are there really, O
>      Yagnavalkya?'
>      'Two,' he said.
>      'Yes,' he said, and asked
>      again:'How many gods
>      are there really, O
>      Yagnavalkya?'
>      'One and a half
>      (adhyardha),' he said.
>      'Yes,' he said, and asked
>      again: 'How many gods
>      are there really, O
>      Yagnavalkya?'
>      'One,' he said.
>      'Yes,' he said, and
>      asked: 'Who are these
>      three and three
>      hundred, three and
>      three thousand?'
> 2. Yagnavalkya replied:
>      'They are only the
>      various powers of them,
>      in reality there are only
>      thirty-three gods.'
>      He asked: 'Who are
>      those thirty-three?'
>      Yagnavalkya replied:
>      'The eight Vasus,the
>      eleven Rudras, the
>      twelve Adityas. They
>      make thirty-one, and
>      Indra and Pragapati
>      make the thirty-three.'
> 3. He asked: 'Who are
>      the Vasus.'
>      Yagnavalkya replied:
>      'Agni (fire), Prithivi
>      (earth), Vayu (air),
>      Antariksha (sky), Aditya
>      (sun), Dyu (heaven),
>      Kandramas (moon), the
>      Nakshatras (stars), these
>      are the Vasus, for in
>      them all that dwells
>      (this world) rests; and
>      therefore they are called
>      Vasus.'
> 4. He asked: 'Who are
>      the Rudras?'
>      Yagnavalkya replied:
>      'These ten vital breaths
>      (pranas, the senses, i. e.
>      the five gnanendriyas,
>      and the five
>      karmendriyas), and
>      Atman, as the eleventh.
>      When they depart from
>      this mortal body, they
>      make us cry (rodayanti),
>      and because they make
>      us cry, they are called
>      Rudras.'
> 5. He asked: 'Who are
>      the Adityas?'
>      Yagnavalkya replied:
>      'The twelve months of
>      the year, and they are
>      Adityas, because they
>      move along (yanti),
>      taking up everything
>      (adadanah). Because
>      they move along, taking
>      up everything, therefore
>      they are called Adityas.'
> 6. He asked: 'And who is
>      Indra, and who is
>      Pragapati?'
>      Yagnavalkya replied:'
>      Indra is thunder,
>      Pragapati is the
>      sacrifice.'
>      He asked: 'And what is
>      the thunder?'
>      Yagnavalkya replied:
>      'The thunderbolt.'
>      He asked: 'And what is
>      the sacrifice?'
>      Yagnavalkya replied:
>      'The (sacrificial)
>      animals.'
> 7. He asked: 'Who are
>      the six?'
>      Yagnavalkya replied:
>      'Agni (fire), Prithivi
>      (earth), Vayu (air),
>      Antariksha (sky), Aditya
>      (sun), Dyu (heaven), they
>      are the six, for they are
>      all this, the six.'
> 8. He asked: 'Who are
>      the three gods?'
>      Yagnavalkya replied:
>      'These three worlds, for
>      in them all these gods
>      exist.'
>      He asked: 'Who are the
>      two gods?'
>      Yagnavalkya replied:
>      'Food and breath.'
>      He asked: 'Who is the
>      one god and a half?'
>      Yagnavalkya replied: 'He
>      that blows.'
> 9. Here they say: 'How is
>      it that he who blows like
>      one only, should be
>      called one and a half
>      (adhyardha)?' And the
>      answer is: 'Because,
>      when the wind was
>      blowing, everything grew
>      (adhyardhnot).'
>
> He asked: 'Who is the
>   one god?'
>   Yagnavalkya replied:
>   'Breath (prana), and he
>   is Brahman (the
>   Sutratman), and they
>   call him That (tyad).'
>
> — [Brihadaranyaka upnishada:second adhyaye:brahmana 9](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/upanishads/brihad.asp)

Comment: I have read all the posts mentioned above and I came up with the following conclusions(I can't say for sure that I right):
1.All Gods mentioned in the Vedas are supreme.
2.This concept does not apply for the Puranas.

I have a doubt,if all the vedic Gods are Supreme and all need to be given equal importance,then how are we going to pray all these Gods if one does not have enough time .

Comment: @Effin forest all gods are equal that's why you can choose a one god but not to make others inferior considering them as a part of your god.
All gods are one but there are prime ones like rudra vishnu bramha which constitute the three forms of brahman if you read the oldest purans like vayu and the second holds matsya you will find that inspite of recognising one god coming like vishnu, rudra or bramha they say brahmana devided itself into three so all are one in udyoga parva krishna too say that other gods are part of his body so choose any one even you can choose a guru too.

Comment: That is a very good explanation.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Am guessing that the ultimate goal of an individual is to attain brahman.

Comment: Yes that's true it was just an answer to your query. The real goal is above all gods ok i will give you these links check them out that:— https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23894/is-any-scriptures-says-that-without-chanting-the-names-of-the-god-we-are-all-l/23899#23899   

just get to the brihadaranyaka story given there by me. 

**Gods are great because they have the knowledge of spirit** — https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21787/why-god-viraat-purush-created-devatas-to-enjoy-and-humans-to-suffer/21789#21789 read the story there

**Because brahmana is above gods**

Comment: Bro do you have more links as above related to brahmana? Now I am starting to understand the concept of Brahmana better.Give me all the available links if possible.And thanks once again.

Comment: Okay @Effin forest if you want to get under it the best thing i will suggest is to go through the principal upnishads 10 main upnishads are taken from vedic samhitas,aranyakas,brahmanas. so i will suggest to read upnishads as reading halh will not be pretty.
**Okay for a intro you should see this**:— https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahman
& **this**:— https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ātman_(Hinduism)

Although you can read upnishads online and can download it as pdf if you want i can give you some good upnishad verses just comment . :) ;)

Comment: Yes,that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72750/discussion-between-fierce-lord-and-elfin-forest).

Comment: How.is this answer relatet to lord Ganesha?